# Hyperledger Fabric Java chaincode install throws error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

> 2017-08-22 07:12:36.535 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
>   2017-08-22 07:12:36.535 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
>   2017-08-22 07:12:36.536 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
>   Error: Java chaincode is work-in-progress and disabled
>   Usage:
>     peer chaincode install [flags]

Flags:

Answer (score 1):

You can't install yet a java chaincode. It's not supported in v1.0

Comment: Thank you, I have modify the fabric source code and recompile to support java, but only for some limit methods.

Comment: correct, Java chaincode is incomplete and not mature. It should only be used as an experiment.